# Editing data in grid vs using an update script

Tags: sql, oracle, character-encoding, oracle-sqldeveloper, toad

I tried using Toad 12.1 DBA and SQLDeveloper to achieve my goal but i got same results.

When i update NVARCHAR2 cell in **grid** result, i can set and commit '€' sign as value. But when i execute an update script to do the same thing, it prints '?' character as data.

Here is the result when i edit and commit data in grid:

[image]

Here is the problem when i use update script to do the same thing:

[image]

I tried using differend NLS_LANG parameters but they did not work either.
AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8ISO8859P9
AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL16UTF16

Database NLS parameters is here:

```
SELECT * FROM NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS where PARAMETER in ('NLS_CHARACTERSET','NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET');

PARAMETER               VALUE
------------            ------------
NLS_CHARACTERSET        WE8ISO8859P9
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET  AL16UTF16
```

Create script for the simple table:

```
CREATE TABLE AAA
(
  NVARCHAR2COL  NVARCHAR2(50)
);
```

I also tried using sqlplus to execute update script, but it printed question mark as data as well.

Edit: one more thing, using update script with unistr function works but i need to update data by using readable text:

```
UPDATE AAA SET NVARCHAR2COL = unistr('\20AC');
COMMIT;
```

Solution: using @Nationalized annotation on my JPA entities for NVARCHAR fields solved my problem.

Comment: You're showing the output of a script running window. Just to eliminate the obvious, please confirm that the outcome is still `?` when queried in the data grid.

Comment: outcome is question mark in data grid too.

Answer (score 0):

Default data type of [Text Literal](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm#i42617) is CHAR. CHAR strings can contain only ASCII symbols and there is no `'€'` symbol in ASCII table, so `'€'` is converted to `'?'` during statement compilation.

To use national character set string value must be prefixed with `N`. `N` function converts the data at compilation time to NCHAR.

`UPDATE AAA SET NVARCHAR2COL = N'€';` should work.

Alternatively `UPDATE AAA SET NVARCHAR2COL = to_nchar('€');` can be used.

When updating a value in a grid the development tool does the same transparently for the user.